# AWS create an EC2 instance when accessed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I currently have an EC2 instance that is on constantly, but has very low usage. I wish to shut down the instance when not in use and restart the instance when it is accessed.

It can be turned off automatically with CloudWatch Alarms fairly easily (tutorial here: https://successengineer.medium.com/how-to-automatically-turn-off-your-ec2-instance-in-2021-b73374e51090 ).

What I cannot find is a way to start the instance automatically when there is an incoming request, given that there are no other instances active.

Currently users arrive by redirection from a Route 53 record (policy: simple, type: A).
The Route 53 record can be changed to make this possible.

Comment: "an incoming request" to what? To the instance itself? API gateway? Lambda function?

Comment: "an incoming request" being someone accessing the website, where ever that may direct (currently to the instance)

Comment: It's not possible without a fully custom solution.

Comment: My question is about how to make that custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the request is sent to the EC2 instance via an A-Record, then it is *not* possible to 'activate' the EC2 instance. This is because the request is being sent to the IP address of an instance that is turned off.

One option would be to provide a way for users to Start the instance, and after 1-2 minutes they could access the instance. Some ways to trigger the instance to start are:

- Use the AWS CLI to call `StartInstances()` (but this requires AWS credentials)
- Use a web browser to access a URL, which triggers an AWS Lambda function, which calls `StartInstances()`

If you do not want users to first Start the instance and wait until it is available, you'll need to send the requests to something that is *not* the EC2 instance. That 'something' could then check that the instance is running (and Start the instance if it is not running), and then forward the request to the instance. Since you are probably doing this to save money, you presumably don't want to use something that is "always on" to do this task.

You should be able to create an AWS Lambda function with a web-accessible URL, so that requests are sent to the Lambda function instead of the instance. The Lambda function would confirm that the instance is running and then forward the request to the instance, and then pass back the response to the user. OR, it could return an **HTTP redirect** to send the user to the instance. (So, the URL will change between the original request and where the response comes from.)

**Bottom line:** There is no *easy* way to achieve what you want. You could use auto-scaling to handle variable loads, but that assumes that at least one instance is always running. If an instance is off, it *cannot* respond to requests sent to the instance.